# In ruby, how do you select the first hash entry whose key is the first matching entry of an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, select

The goal is something like the following code:

```
h={ i:4, j:3, k:2}
a=[ :f, :g, :j, :z, :i]
h.get_first_matching_in(a)
=> :j
h.select first_from(a)
=> :j
```

What should go in `.get_first_matching_in` or `first_from`?

Comment: Try building the methods yourself then we can help if you still have trouble

Comment: Keep in mind that to use the syntax you propose, you will need to monkey-patch `Hash`.

Comment: @moveson, no, its a valid syntax.

Comment: @Ilya I don't think `h.get_first_matching_in(a)` is an existing instance method of `Hash` ;)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko, I think it's just an instance of method name should be implemented in answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would write like:

```
(a & h.keys).first
 => :j
```

Or:

```
a.find { |e| h[e] }
```

Comment: Ok, in the mid time I found `(a.map { |e| h.assoc e  }).compact[0][0]`, but your solution is obviously far better.

Comment: @phychoslave The next appropriate step would be to accept the answer as correct.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't able to do it immediately, there is a minimum time you must wait to accept an aswer @moveson